# Retrieve variable from child scope

Tags: cmake

I have a third-party CMake package that does some non-trivial work in its own `CMakeLists.txt` but doesn't set the resulting variables with `PARENT_SCOPE` so a `CMakeLists.txt` file that has added the project directory doesn't get to look at the variables.

Tacking a few `set` commands with `PARENT_SCOPE` to the end of the package's `CMakeLists.txt` works fine but is there any trick that would allow a parent scope to extract variables from a child scope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [get_directory_property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/get_directory_property.html) command for that purpose:

```
add_subdirectory(sources)
...
get_directory_property(variableValue DIRECTORY sources DEFINITION variableName)
```

Comment: it can only retrieve from its direct child. It cannot retrieve values from its grand-children.